# Trouble understanding a criteria for integrability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

> Let $f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and $f ≥ 0$. Prove that if the set $\{x\in[0,1]|f(x)\geq \lambda \}$ is finite for every $λ > 0$ then $f$ is integrable.

I'm having trouble understanding this criteria for integrability. I know that if a function is continuous on an interval then it is integrable on that interval and also that monotonicity implies integrability  but I couldn't wrap my mind around this one. I assume that the set being finite implies monotonicity but I haven't really been able to show it, I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Most definitely NOT monotonic. What I missed the first time through was $f\ge 0$. You will need to apply the standard criterion for integrability: In this case, use the hypothesis to show that given any $\epsilon>0$, there is a partition with $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$.

Comment: You should play around with the condition some. Write down 3 functions satisfying it. Try to write down another that's (quite) different from the first three. Why are these functions integrable? Then what @TedShifrin suggests.